# How is it possible to get full intellisene on Pybind11 in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, pybind11

I'm working with Pybind11 in `Visual Studio 2015`. I configured the projects necessary properties. that is I set the include and library directories accordingly. That is I set them to these values:

Include Directories:

```
L:\FV\pybind11\pybind11\include;C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\include;L:\FV\pybind11\pybind11\pybind11;$(IncludePath)
```

and for Library Directories:

```
C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\Lib;C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\libs;$(LibraryPath)
```

and currently everything seems working and compilations succeeds.
However, I get wiggly error lines when trying  to use different methods, classes, etc from `Pybind11`, which is related to the intellisense failing to get the needed information.
This is how it looks :

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this and get full intellisense in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded to `Visual Studio 2019` and the intellisense is working perfectly. This seems like an inherent problem in VS2015 and its lack of ability to properly index and provide intellisense.